# Copy files from remote linux server to local directory continuously

Tags: linux, files, remote, synchronization

A process on remote server R is writing files to a specific directory continuously. I need to download the files to my local server L as soon as the files are available. And move/rename the files on R so that they do not get included again. I was wondering if there is any builtin command like scp that could do this out of the box?

Otherwise my strategy would be as follows:

1. List the files on R using sftp and save the list in a variable
2. For each file, download the file to L with .tmp extension
3. After the download is complete remove the .tmp
4. Move the file on R to another folder on R

Cron the above script every 5 mins. If there is already a script running, then exit.

Is there any problem with the above solution that you can see? Or is there a better solution?

**Limitations**:

1. I have to pull from R to L
2. I do not have much control of R except to rename or move files to another folder on R
3. I do not want to delete files on R, preferably move to another folder or rename
4. Another process on L would be moving files from the downloaded directory

Comment: 1. If you transfer a file from R that's still being written you'll land with a truncated file on L. 2. Why not use `rsync`, which can be configured (a) not to transfer files you've already transferred successfully (b) to remove the files from R that have been successfully copied to L. 3. Can you write the files on R with a `.tmp` suffix and rename (still on R) only on successful completion? If so you can arrange for your file transfer process to ignore `*.tmp` files. 4. Do you have to pull from L, or can you push from R? Please consider responding - in your question rather than in a comment.

Comment: Would it be an option to have the remote R mount a network directory from your local server L, and then continiously directly write to this network directory? In this way, the files would automatically land on L, without explicit copying...